# Create and specify a QLabel after mouse pressed on another QLabel in QT

Tags: qt, events, mouse, qlabel

Ok so what i'm trying to do is to create a new QLabel added to a QList and put it where I clicked on the other QLabel where I clicked.

So here is my code:

```
    class CustomLabel : public QLabel
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        CustomLabel();
        void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* event);

    private:
        QList<QLabel *> pointsL;
        QList<QPoint *> points;
    };


    void CustomLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        points << new QPoint(event->pos());
        pointsL << new QLabel(this);
        pointsL.at(pointsL.size()-1)->setText("+");
        pointsL.at(pointsL.size()-1)->setGeometry(QRect(points.at(points.size()-1)->rx(),, points.at(points.size()-1)->ry(), 1, 1));
    }
```

I also tried:

```
pointsL.at(pointsL.size()-1)->move(points.at(points.size()-1)->rx(), points.at(points.size()-1)->ry());
```

and this:

```
    void CustomLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        points << new QPoint(event->pos());
        pointsL << new QLabel(this);
        pointsL.at(pointsL.size()-1)->setText("+");
        pointsL.at(pointsL.size()-1)->move(*points.at(points.size()-1));
        pointsL.at(pointsL.size()-1)->setTabOrder(pointsL.at(pointsL.size()-1), this);
    }
```

When I click on the Custom Label nothing happens. The constructor is empty.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Don't think QLabel can be used as a container widget, i.e. it cannot have another QLabel as a child like that and display it. That might the reason the new label is not showing up. I am not sure I fully understand your case. Have you tried e.g. a QGridLayout? The mouse events need to be handled by a parent QWidget then.

Comment: I found an alternative to the problem but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

New widgets added after the parent is already visible on screen should be shown explicitly unless they are in a layout.

So basically you should add:

```
pointsL.back()−>show();
```